# Unknown root level key connection and provisioner

Tags: terraform

I'm creating an ec2 instance and while doing terraform plan I get the error Unknown root level key for connection and provisioner. I'm using the latest version of terraform. Here is the complete code of my .tf file.

Here is my error message

```
Error: Unsupported block type

  on ec2-dev\ec2.tf line 39, in module "ec2__application":
  39:   connection {

Blocks of type "connection" are not expected here.

Error: Unsupported block type

  on ec2-dev\ec2.tf line 44, in module "ec2__application":
  44:   provisioner "file" {

Blocks of type "provisioner" are not expected here.


Error: Unsupported block type

  on ec2-dev\ec2.tf line 49, in module "ec2__application":
  49:   provisioner "file" {

Blocks of type "provisioner" are not expected here.
```

terraform

```
module "ec2__application" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version = "1.19.0"
  name           = "${var.ec2__application["name"]}"
  instance_count = "${var.ec2__application["count"]}"

  ami                    = "${data.aws_ami.ami.id}"
  private_ip             = "${var.ec2__application["private-ip"]}"
  instance_type          = "${var.ec2__application["type"]}"
  key_name               = "${var.ec2__application["ssh_key"]}"
  monitoring             = true
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${other module reference here}"]
  subnet_id              = "${var.ec2__application["subnet_id"]}"

  associate_public_ip_address = false
  disable_api_termination     = true

  tags = {
    name = "${var.ec2__application["name"]}"
  }

  instance_count = "${var.ec2__application["count"]}"
  ami            = "${data.aws_ami.ami.id}"
  instance_type  = "${var.ec2__application["type"]}"
  subnet_id      = "${var.ec2__application["subnet_id"]}"
  key_name       = "${var.ec2__application["ssh_key"]}"

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ec2-user"
    private_key = "test.pem"
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "test.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/test.sh"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo chmod +x /tmp/test.sh",
      "sudo su - root 'bash test.sh' &"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact error and also make sure that your code in the question is exactly what you are running?

Comment: Error are clearly saying that, these blocks(connection,provisioner) shouldn't be there. That is not valid location for those blocks. Check [ec2-terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws/2.4.0)

Comment: @AniketKulkarni Can you please give the link where I can find examples which has connection and provisioner. I used the same code which I posted above and was working fine. Not sure what went wrong now.